# Find the value of $\int^5_0f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, functions, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Let $f(-x)=2f(x)$. If $\int^5_{-5}f(x)dx=3$, then $\int^5_0f(x)dx$ is...

(A) -5

(B) -3

(C) -1

(D) 0

(E) 1

My attempt:

$\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=\frac{f(-x)}{2}\\
\int^5_{-5}f(x)dx&=\int^0_{-5}f(x)dx+\int^5_0f(x)dx\\
&=\frac{-1}{2}\int^0_{-5}f(-x)dx+\int^5_0f(x)dx\\
\text{Let }u=-x \text{, then }du=-dx\\
\int^5_{-5}f(x)dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int^5_{0}f(u)du+\int^5_0f(x)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int^5_{0}f(x)dx+\int^5_0f(x)dx\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\int^5_0f(x)dx\\\\
\frac{3}{2}\int^5_0f(x)dx&=3\\
\int^5_0f(x)dx&=2
\end{aligned}$

The answer is not on the option.

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split up the integral
$$
\int_{-5}^5 f(x)dx = \int_{-5}^0 f(x)dx + \int_{0}^5 f(x)dx = 3
$$

We change the bounds of the negative integral and apply the hypothesis

$$
\int_{-5}^0 f(x)dx = \int_{0}^5 f(-x)dx = \int_{0}^5 2 f(x)dx = 2 \int_{0}^5 f(x)dx
$$

Ergo
$$
3 = \int_{-5}^0 f(x)dx + \int_{0}^5 f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^5 f(x)dx + \int_{0}^5 f(x)dx = 3 \int_{0}^5 f(x)dx
$$

We conclude that $\int_{0}^5 f(x)dx = 1$

Knowing the answer, can you find the mistake in your original reasoning?

Comment: I can't just substitute $f(x)$ with $\frac{f(-x)}{2}$?

Comment: So this is actually a trick question - the only $f$ that satisfies $f(-x) = 2f(x)$ is the constant zero function $f(x)=0$!

Because suppose that $f(x) \ne 0$ for a certain $x$. Then $f(-x) = 2 f(x) \ne 0$, and applying the hipothesis again $f(x) = f(-(-x)) = 2 f(-x) = 2 \cdot 2 f(x)$ which is absurd.

I suppose that the authors of the exercise forgot to mention that the hypothesis only applies for $x > 0$, in which case my solution works but yours does not (since it is applying the hypothesis for x < 0).

Comment: Why my method only works if $x<0$? At a glance, the difference only you change the bound of negative integral and mine replace $f(x)$ with $\frac{f(-x)}{2}$. Thank you.

Comment: @airlangga the condition in the statement is incoherent, so it can lead to any result.

Comment: To fix it you need to let it only apply for x < 0 or for x > 0. And your choice of whether it should apply for x < 0 or for x > 0 leads to a different result